# how i can use like statement in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, t-sql

i am adding parameter by

```
qry = qry.Replace("{criteria}", "info.abc LIKE '%?val%'");
```

command not worked if i removed `' '` from the command then it give a error how i can search the table in c#

Comment: Post the entire query.

Comment: Show the original query template.

Comment: Need more information if you want some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the syntax of [TSQL - Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) you require to put search value between ' '

Example :

```
WHERE title LIKE '%computer%'
```

syntax

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do this which is more explicit - and in my opinion more readable because it avoids the crockety parts of the SQL syntax:

```
SqlDataReader r = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM the_table").ExecuteReader();
object[] values = new object[5000];
r.GetValues(values);
foreach (string value in values)
    if (value.Length > 4)
        if (value.Contains("val"))
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE the_table SET value = 'newValue' WHERE "+
                           "value = '"+value+"'").ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This solution has a risk of sql injection (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It would be better to use parameterized queries. Also, it it can have a high impact on performance (it needs to run as many queries as there are records in "the_table")

Comment: @ckarras: Thanks, didn't know about the SQL inject attack.  Performance shouldn't be a worry, though.  Focus first on getting it right, then on getting it fast if you need to.

Comment: - `Focus first on getting it right, then on getting it fast if you need to`. Where is the connection string used? Without connection string how will it know which database and which instance to execute command against?